# Passing variables from HTML to PHP without forms

Tags: php, html, variables

This may not be possible, which is why I can't find the answer, but is it possible to pass variables from HTML to PHP without a form?

I'm trying to create a template that will use HTML I import into a Wordpress Page. I want to be able to put certain divs in different parts of the template. Think of a table, where I put the divs in different cells.

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

edit:
I haven't created the template code yet, since I'm not sure how to without the answer to my question. But here's an example of the code I'm pulling from:

<div id="text-column">

<div class="scarlet_underline">
<p class="toc_dept"><a href="XXX"><img src="XXX" width="112" height="36" alt="Forum" border="0"/></a></p>
<p class="toc_item"><a href="XXX">University futures; Science’s influence; Can geoengineering be green?; Mineral reserves; Transforming conservation; Intelligent transportation; Personal health records.</a></p>
</div>

<div class="scarlet_underline">
<p class="toc_dept"><a href="XXX"><img src="XXX" width="112" height="36" alt="From the Hill" border="0"/></a></p>
<p class="toc_item"><a href="XXX">House approves bill to reform offshore oil drilling; Senate committee approves competitiveness bill; GAO investigates genetic test companies; House, Senate committees lay out plans for NASA’s future; Federal science and technology in brief.</a></p>
</div>

So ideally, these two "scarlet_underline" divs would each be pulled separately, maybe by using the alt attribute? The template code would be something like:

<div class="forum"><?php *code that pulls that div* ?></div>

<other code other code>

<div class="hill"><?php *code that pulls that div* ?></div>

Comment: Can you show a bit of what your code is?

Comment: This is ambiguous. Please explain the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass variables from HTML to PHP without a form?

Yes, that is possible. PHP automatically creates variables for Cookies and parameters in the Query part of the request URI. Both can be send from the browser without any HTML form.

```
http://example.com/path/to/index.php?type=animal&name=narwhal#nose
\__/   \_________/ \_______________/ \_____________________/ \___/
 |          |             |                    |               |
scheme   authority       path                query          fragment
                                             ^^^^^
```

This request URI will make PHP create two entries in the  [`$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/reserved.variables.get):

```
$_GET['type'];    # animal
$_GET['name'];    # narwhal
```

See as well [Variables From External Sources<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/language.variables.external).

Comment: Nice diagram but how does it help?

Comment: It explains the construct of a URL and how variables can be passed to PHP in the query string.

Comment: Thank you hakre, that does help my understanding of PHP, but I think the code I want to use is too long for a url. (Not your fault, I didn't specify. I've added some sample code in my original post.)

Comment: Yes that can be. If it is too long for the URL, then you need to do a POST request which is normally a form. Technically you can do that with javascript (kown as AJAX) without having a form. If it's too large, you need to learn about AJAX first (it's not that complicated and Wordpress ships with Jquery which helps your for the javascript part of AJAX. See also codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

Comment: Thank you hakre! I am looking into AJAX now, and hope I'll be able to make it work!